# How to return value from id after format?

Tags: javascript

I am not a programmer or even great at coding. I just go around internet and customise some code that I find interesting to make it how I would like it to be.

Here's the situation that I would like it to be solve. I am trying to make comma as a thousand separator with using <span id""> because the data comes from there.

The script work fine after long hours of search. But I want the formatted script data to return value to my <span id""> back. Is it possible?

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Online HTML Editor</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<span id="cuba">4448948</span>
<br/><br/>

<script>
 var angka = document.getElementById('cuba').textContent;
 var reverse = angka.toString().split('').reverse().join(''),
 ribuan = reverse.match(/\d{1,3}/g);
 ribuan = ribuan.join(',').split('').reverse().join('');
document.write(ribuan)
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I am not good at any certain area of coding, so I just go around the internet to find the solution. I am hoping and expecting there's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `document.write` with `document.getElementById('cuba').innerHTML= ribuan;`:

```js
var angka = document.getElementById('cuba').textContent;
var reverse = angka.toString().split('').reverse().join(''),
  ribuan = reverse.match(/\d{1,3}/g);
ribuan = ribuan.join(',').split('').reverse().join('');
document.getElementById('cuba').innerHTML = ribuan;
```

```html
<span id="cuba">4448948</span>
```

Comment: Remember to mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem. It helps the community as well as gives you rep.